Cannot forward jupyter notebook port through tunnel
trying to run a notebook on a remote machine... I start the notebook on the local machine like so:
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889

resulting in the following message:
[I 09:51:45.485 NotebookApp] Loading IPython parallel extension
[I 09:51:45.488 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /mnt/16tb_hdd/user/Notebooks
[I 09:51:45.488 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 09:51:45.488 NotebookApp] http://alpha:8889/?token=0b021f5e20f2b5bf0b650ef34f691500b3880783bea45420
[I 09:51:45.488 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=0b021f5e20f2b5bf0b650ef34f691500b3880783bea45420
[I 09:51:45.488 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:51:45.490 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/alpha/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-16487-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://alpha:8889/?token=0b021f5e20f2b5bf0b650ef34f691500b3880783bea45420
     or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=0b021f5e20f2b5bf0b650ef34f691500b3880783bea45420

Of course going to this address on that machine opens the notebook as expected.
Now, I am trying to forward to another machine:
 ssh -NfL localhost:8888:localhost:8889 alpha@pc.com
 ssh -NfL localhost:8889:alpha:8889 alpha@pc.com
 ssh -NfL localhost:8887:127.0.0.1:8889 alpha@pc.com

I tried all three of these, but any time I go to localhost:8888,8889, or 8887 I am met with the following message:
Unable to connect

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8887.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is        permitted to access the web.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here... the base machine running the server is ubuntu and the one I'm trying to forward to is alma9 if that matters?
I also checked:
jupyter notebook --generate-config
Overwrite /home/jupyter_notebook_config.py with default config? [y/N]n
cat /home/jupyter_notebook_config.py

import os
if 'ROOTSYS' in os.environ:
    # Prefer using JSROOT from ROOTSYS if defined
    c.NotebookApp.extra_static_paths.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ROOTSYS'], 'js/'))
else:
    # Fall back to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/CMAKE_INSTALL_JSROOTDIR, e.g., for a system installation
    c.NotebookApp.extra_static_paths.append(os.path.join("/home/alpha/packages/root-v6-24-00", "js"))

c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'

which looks fine to me?

Is the port on the remote computer set to be open in the security settings?

Its an ubuntu device? How can I check this? I can connect to the remote pc from the local pc so It must be open no?


Skipping adding existing rule

Skipping adding existing rule (v6)```
I guess the port was already open no?

Apparently it was. I'm not seeing where things are going wrong then. Is this at a place where the network is more secure than you may be anticipating?

it certainly is but both devices are on site, one is managed entirely by me (on their network) so in theory I can make it as unsecure as I want it to be

Yes, but I wonder if the network is more limited than you expect even though it is internal that you are trying to contact? I'm not knowledgeable on the internal security because I usually just compare accessing external things from my home later. I'm not concerning with internal to internal communication.
